# How to dynamically add class methods to Rails Models using module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, meta-search

I have this code on model class to add search methods to be used by `meta_search` gem:

```
class Model

  self.def created_at_lteq_at_end_of_day(date)
     where("created_at <= ?", DateTime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').end_of_day)
  end

  search_methods :created_at_lteq_at_end_of_day
end
```

This code add search methods to date field. 
Now, is needed to add this search method to other classes and with others fields. 
To achieve this, this module was created:

**lib/meta_search/extended_search_methods.rb**

```
module MetaSearch
  module ExtendedSearchMethods
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end


    module ClassMethods
      def add_search_by_end_of_day(field, format)

        method_name = "#{field}_lteq_end_of_day"

        define_method method_name do |date|
          where("#{field} <= ?", DateTime.strptime(date, format).end_of_day) 
        end

        search_methods method_name
      end
    end
  end
end


class Model
   include MetaSearch::ExtendedSearchMethods
   add_search_by_end_of_day :created_at, '%d/%m/%Y'
end
```

After add the module, this errors starts to rise:

```
undefined method `created_at_lteq_end_of_day' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fcd3cdb0e28>
```

**Other solution:**

change `define_method` to `define_singleton_method`

Comment: Did you `include MetaSearch`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides a pretty idiomatic and cool way of doing that, `ActiveSupport::Concern` :

```
module Whatever
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
        def say_hello_to(to)
            puts "Hello #{to}"
        end
    end
end

class YourModel
    include Whatever

    say_hello_to "someone"
end
```

See the [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). Although it is not directly related to your question, the `included` method is incredibly useful for models or controllers (scopes, helper methods, filters, etc), plus `ActiveSupport::Concern` handles dependencies between modules for free (both as in freedom and as in beer).

Comment: Great solution that still works wonders. If refactoring code from a model into a module, don't forget to remove the `self.` from the beginning of the method name after putting it in the `module ClassMethods` block.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a `class << self` so you are working in a singleton class.

```
module Library
  module Methods
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def add_foo
        class << self
          define_method "foo" do
            puts "Foo!"
          end #define_method
        end #class << self
      end #add_foo
    end #ClassMethods
  end #Methods
end #Library

class Test
  include Library::Methods

  add_foo
end

puts Test.foo
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great for me.